# POSTGRESQL - "ERROR: operator does not exist: interval <= date"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, types

Trying to create a CASE field that shows active/inactive accounts. Active accounts have placed an order within the last 90 days.

I'm running into issues with data types and can't figure out a solution. Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (accountid)
    accountid, customer, round(AVG(qty),2) AS average_order_qty, ROUND(AVG(total),2) AS avg_order_rev, (CURRENT_DATE - MAX(date)) as days_since_order, (CURRENT_DATE - MAX(date)) as active,
        CASE 
            WHEN (CURRENT_DATE - MAX(date)) <= CURRENT_DATE - 90 THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
        END
FROM m2m_kit_total
GROUP BY accountid, customer
ORDER BY accountid, MAX(date) DESC NULLS LAST;
```

And here's the error code I get in return:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: interval <= date
LINE 4:    WHEN (CURRENT_DATE - MAX(date)) <= CURRENT_DATE - 90 THEN...
                                           ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 261
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware that your condition `(CURRENT_DATE - MAX(date)) <= CURRENT_DATE - 90` is equivalent to `MAX(date) >= 90`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the logic that you want:

```
SELECT accountid, customer, round(AVG(qty), 2) AS average_order_qty, 
       ROUND(AVG(total), 2) AS avg_order_rev,
       (CURRENT_DATE - MAX(date)) as days_since_order,
       (CASE WHEN MAX(date) >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '90 DAY' THEN 'Yes'
             ELSE 'No'
        END) as is_active
FROM m2m_kit_total
GROUP BY accountid, customer
ORDER BY accountid, MAX(date) DESC NULLS LAST;
```

This is a simple comparison of two dates.  It should not have any issues.

I am also guessing that each account has only one customer, so this returns one row per `accountid`, without relying on `distinct on`.

Comment: YES! Thanks, Gordon! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (accountid)
    accountid, customer, round(AVG(qty),2) AS average_order_qty, ROUND(AVG(total),2) AS avg_order_rev, (CURRENT_DATE - MAX(date)) as days_since_order, (CURRENT_DATE - MAX(date)) as active,
        CASE 
            WHEN ((CURRENT_DATE - MAX(date)) = (CURRENT_DATE - 90)) THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
        END
FROM m2m_kit_total
GROUP BY accountid, customer
ORDER BY accountid, MAX(date) DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: interval = date
    LINE 4:             WHEN ((CURRENT_DATE - MAX(date)) =     (CURRENT_DATE...
                                                         ^
    HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
    SQL state: 42883
    Character: 280

Comment: What is this 90? which you are substracting? is it date or no. of days/

Comment: it is number of days. Gordon solved my problem in his response above. Thanks for your help!